# How to make a command that stores channelID in database?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, discord.js

How can I make a command that stores a channelID in a database, also by database, kind of like a big text file on my machine that has a server id, then a channel id. How should I go about this?

Im using:
discord.js
sqlite3
sequelize

How i think it would go would be:
User: ?setlog #channelmentionhere
Bot: *makes new entire into a textfile or something*

I've done a ton of research, i cannot understand  much of it, if i did understand it, i would have troubles with it.

My bot code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();


    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type !== 'text') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
        }
    }

    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

    try {
        command.execute(message, args, user);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I bet it works on Mars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Quick.db (`npm i quick.db`) This database stores persistently (doesn't wipe on bot restarts)

In the following code snippets, I am using quick.db but this shouldn't be too hard using a Json file.

Setting the channelID per guild: (You don't have to use member but I do out of habit)

```
let member = message.guild.member(message.member);
db.set(`${member.guild.id}-modlogs`, message.mentions.channels.first().id);
```

Grabbing the Database in other commands then sending the channel messages:

```
let dbchannelID = db.get(`${member.guild.id}-modlogs`)
let msgchannel = member.guild.channels.get(dbchannelID);
msgchannel.send("Blah Blah")
```

Explaining the `db.set` part:

So `db.set` is setting the database and the database here would be `modlogs`. The text between `db.set` & `modlogs` is how you want to set it as, in this it is setting per guild. You can change that to `message.author.id` and it would set to the author etc.

Hopefully, this helped in some way.

Comment: Is there any setup for my bot folder or anything, like any new files/folders? I just want to make sure.

Comment: I tested out your code, and it didn't work, i get a error saying "db is not defined".

Here is my pastebin script: https://pastebin.com/i4KNF26C

Comment: Resolved the problem above, made the code two seprate commands

Comment: Hopefully, I helped in some way, good luck with the rest of your bot.